# span with contenteditable attribute makes tag next to it go to new line

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

Hi I need to display two spans alternately with contenteditable attribute and few without it. That spans should behaves simillar to textarea behaviour. I mean should be displayed inline to each other.

Problem starts when I start to play with Enter. When I type Enter at the end(after the last letter) of the editable span next span goes to new line(thats correct), but I am not able to turn it back(span doesn't come back to one line as before).

That behaves correct when for example I type enter before last letter of editable span, then I am able to remove enter correctly.

```css
.container{
  
}

.element{
  outline: none;
}

.specialElement{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="element" contenteditable="true" innerHtml="'test'">test</span>
  <span class="specialElement">some tag</span>
  <span class="element" contenteditable="true" innerHtml="'test2'">test2</span>
</div>
```

Here is fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/twLu9eac/6/

[Here is screen of that incorrect situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQDcm.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this css attribute to your editable spans

```css
.container .element{
  display: inline-block !important;
}

.element{
  outline: none;
}

.specialElement{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="element" contenteditable="true" innerHtml="'test'">test</span>
  <span class="specialElement">some tag</span>
  <span class="element" contenteditable="true" innerHtml="'test2'">test2</span>
</div>
```

It has a little tricky behaviour but does what you want

Comment: Not really, now the "some tag" goes to new line but it need to go exactly under the "test". I mean that have to be inline just like a textarea field.

Comment: @Ballkar ok, for a better solution if you don't know where to whatch I'm pretty sure that with javascript playing with the `onkeyup` event applied on the editable spans will help you in the creating of a logic that handle this problem